# Boolean law simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

How would someone go about simplifying the expression:

$((p \vee r)\wedge((p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge ¬q)))\vee (p \wedge r) \vee \neg(p \vee q) \vee r$

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED: Is this a correct truth table?

[image]

Comment: Start with a truth-table, in order to illustrate to yourself the $4$ possible cases of this expression. And while you're at it, make sure that you illustrate it to the rest of us as well (i.e., show your effort if you're expecting others to make an effort for you).

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me what specific boolean laws are there, because I type boolean laws on youtube it comes up with different kind of boolean laws i.e: AB'C'D + ABC' etcetc.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the $r$, so there are 8 possible cases.

Comment: You really need to add some parentheses!

Comment: Barak, could you check my truth table, please?

Comment: @EbuPotokombe Ok, I will add where I believe parentheses should go. If I am wrong, then you can change it again, but again, you really need some parentheses, because otherwise your expression is not grammatical and we cannot be sure what it is.

Comment: No, your truth table is wrong. You didn't even get simple stuff like $p\wedge q$ correctly (at least the last line). In addition, you've recklessly replaced $\neg(p \vee q)$ with $p \vee q$. More generally, you've replaced the order of the inner expressions, which makes it hard to compute the final expression. By working in a non-orderly-fashioned manner, you've made your entire effort prone to errors, and ended up with a bunch of silly mistakes. Fix up the table, write it down **properly** and **carefully**, then I will be willing to give it a second look.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $(p \land q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) = p \land(q \lor \lnot q) = p\;$ by distributivity and complements;
- $(p \land r) \lor r = r\;$ by absorption;
- $\lnot(p \lor q) = \lnot p \land \lnot q$ by De Morgan's.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  After effecting the simplifications above, the expression becomes:

$$((p \lor r) \land p) \lor r \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$$

More hints:

- $(p \lor r) \land p = p\;$ again by absorption;
- $p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) = (p \lor \lnot p) \land (p \lor \lnot q)=p \lor \lnot q\;$ by distributivity and complements.

Comment: @EbuPotokombe Yes, that's what I am getting. You can doublecheck that with the truth table, of course.

Comment: ((p∨r∨(¬p∧¬q)((p∨r)∧p)∨r∨(¬p∧¬q) and then to pV¬q ((p∨r)∧p)∨r∨(¬p∧¬q) using distrubivity, absorption and compliments, right?

Comment: @EbuPotokombe You should really use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) since it's difficult to read without it. Associativity is also used, which allows reordering the "$\lor$" disjunction terms.

Comment: is the simplified expression "p v ¬q v r" ?

Comment: @EbuPotokombe I answered that when you first asked an hour ago, before you deleted the previous comment.

Comment: Can you answer again, please? Because I can't see what you said as an answer before

Comment: @EbuPotokombe That's the first comment now, since you deleted yours. "*Yes, that's what I am getting. You can doublecheck that with the truth table, of course.*".